# ATTRIBUTEERROR: 'BYTES' OBJECT HAS NO ATTRIBUTE 'getheader'

Tags: sql, python-3.x, web-crawler, urllib

so i am trying to run the initial spider of a webcrawler and i keep getting `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'getheader'` error message. As a method in the spider class, i defined a function to parse and extract html(in strings)  using `getheader()` to access header info but i still keep getting the error message. What attribute can i use in place of `getheader()` or `get()` to make this work? Please help. here is the code:

```
@staticmethod
def gather_links(page_url):
    html_string=''
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(page_url, context=ctx).read()
    if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content Type'):
        html_bytes= response.read()
        html_string=html_bytes.decode()
    finder= LinkFinder(spider.base_url, page_url)
    finder.feed(html_string)
    #except:
    #    print('Error: Can not crawl page')
    #    return set()
```

Comment: Remove the `.read()` when assigning to `response`. `.urlopen(...)` returns the object you want, `.read()` returns the response body (as you correctly do a couple lines later).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i made the adjustment and a few more and the code now runs without any errors but it does not carry out the function of gathering the links on the page crawled to add to the wait list. Though it moves the crawled link from the waiting list to the crawled list. please help i'm i missing something in this function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Python to help any further.

Comment: No worries, i figured it out. Thanks for the help.